# Am I handling "spot the missing DLL" right?

Tags: c#, library, wpf, mvvm

I have a .net 4.5 desktop script which has dependencies on some third party libraries (dll's). These libraries are used in my `MainWindowViewModel`. I need to check that these dll's are present before their absence allow the program to break (which is basically at the starting point of the code). This is how I am handling it at the moment: wrapping the code which fires up the `MainWindowViewModel`'s constructor inside a `try/catch`. Is this the right way to do this?

In my `App.xaml.cs`

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

        //Create the ViewModel to which the main window binds.
        try
        {
            var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            // When the ViewModel asks to be closed, 
            // close the window.
            EventHandler handler = null;
            handler = delegate
            {
                viewModel.RequestClose -= handler;
                window.Close();
            };
            viewModel.RequestClose += handler;

            window.DataContext = viewModel;
            window.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            window.Close();
        }
    }
```

If the dll is missing, running the program causes a message box to pop up (as you see in the code), and tells the user:

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.net.xxxx, version = x.x.xx.x,
>   culture ... or one of the dependencies. The system cannot find the
>   file specified.

I would like to have a better message rather than the whole `exception` body in the message box. Maybe some dedicated method could return the dll name, version, etc. separately rather than me trying to clip it out of the exception.

Comment: Where is the late binding happening? In the *ViewModel*? In the *View*? Is it supposed to be in this code and it's not written yet? As it stands your question isn't very clear. The right way to do what? To display a window?

Comment: I've read some stuff related to `AssemblyResolve`, however, from what this article was referring I couldn't figure out if this is related to my issue or how to implement it. It was called "AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event Tips" from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310675/AppDomain-AssemblyResolve-Event-Tips

Comment: I've added the info you wanted. And the question is, is this the right way to control if the required third party dll is accompanying the executable.

Comment: fair enough. go for your life. sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: @Mat'sMug In fact what I understood is this: if the dll is not installed, the code throw an exception. He open up a window with `ex.Message` that probably contain : `Could not load file or assembly ...`. So I think this is his way of handling the missing dll. So the short answer to your question is no, since you do not directly control if the dll is present or not but just the side effect of it.

Comment: I've retracted both the down and the close vote, since I ended up reviewing your code anyway.. but I still think your question would be much better if you included the "spot the missing dll" code. Cheers! (PS - welcome to CR, feel free to meet the site regulars anytime, in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)).

Comment: Not worth an answer yet, but: I wouldn't catch `Exception`. Instead only catch `LateBindingException `. It's better to always only catch the excepted exception and not to choose it to broad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the code you've posted could very well be doing *anything* that could potentially throw *any* exception.

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
```

By putting this constructor call *outside* the `try` block, any exception thrown in the `MainWindow` constructor will be unhandled and the program will terminate in a not-so-gracious way. I assume the constructor does nothing special, but your `OnStartup` override is also making that assumption; I'd move the call *inside* the `try` block.

```
var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

Your usage of `var` is inconsistent - I'd declare the `MainWindow` with `var` as well, but you could also declare the `MainWindowViewModel` instance with an explicit type; all that matters is consistency.

The fact that the *ViewModel*'s constructor isn't taking any parameters tells me that the `MainWindowViewModel` class is likely to be *tightly coupled* with whatever dependencies it might have; the *ViewModel* could instead be constructor-injected with some *service* whose sole purpose would be to perform the 3rd-party DLL late binding - if that service has its own dependencies, for example a Log4net logger, it can receive it in its own constructor:

```
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LateBindingService))
var service = new LateBindingService(logger);
var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(service);
```

That would make the intent of your code much clearer, and would keep the *ViewModel* class more focused on being a *ViewModel*.

Then if you want to use an IoC container to automatically resolve and inject dependencies, you'll have absolutely nothing to change!

---

I like that you are holding a reference to your `handler` so it can be unregistered, but I find it would be cleaner to just register a private method instead of a delegate:

```
var view = new MainWindow();

var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LateBindingService))
var service = new LateBindingService(logger);
var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(service);

viewModel.RequestClose += ViewModel_RequestClose;
view.DataContext = viewModel;
view.Show();
```

And that would be the whole `try` block.

The `LateBindingService` would be responsible for knowing everything there is to know about the 3rd party DLL, and would expose a method to try loading it.

---

The `catch` block should catch a much more specific exception type than `System.Exception`, since you want to show that message box *if the late binding fails*, not if anything else goes wrong at one point or another in the *View*'s lifetime.

I'd probably have the `LateBindingService` throw some `LateBindingException` which exposes properties for everything there is to know about the missing assembly; the `Message` property would be 100% under *your* control, and then the `catch` block could be like this:

```
catch(LateBindingException exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    viewModel.OnRequestClose();
}
```

Notice that I'm not calling `Close` directly on the view, because I want the handler to unregister itself before exiting, so I'd just have the *ViewModel* expose a method that raises the `RequestClose` event - convention for such methods is `On[EventName]`, so `OnRequestClose`.

Comment: Very Descriptive and great answer. One addition. One of the DLLs I am using is for Log4Net and it's very simple one. All I needed to do is to add it to my `references` and create a `var` in the form of `private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainWindowViewModel));`. Would you be able to expand on your answer about how you're suggesting to move this process into your recommended `var service = new LateBindingService();` ?

Comment: @Mehrad edited; the constructor would have to be something like `public LateBindingService(ILog logger) { _logger = logger; }`, assigning a `private readonly ILog _logger;` field, and then `_logger` can be used as needed inside the `LateBindingService` class. The Ninject IoC container has a `Ninject.Extensions.Logging` namespace that supports Log4Net, you might want to look into that, too.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Assembly.Load (Reflection) to attempt to load the assemblies in question? You know what third party dependencies you have (because you built the app) and this list is fixed. Simply loop through these assemblies and if any do not bind, you have a cleaner name of the assembly to display and you can also have specific messages on how the user could resolve the problem (by installing dependency package or whatever).